# import unicodecsv fails in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7, package, jupyter

I tried to run
import unicodecsv
within jupyter by running a .ipynb file.
It failed.
Then I installed the unicodecsv file through the python install command and found it within c\python27 dir. But still the import did not happen.
How should it be installed. Does it need to be placed within the anaconda installation

Edit :
Error displayed -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9c1521d8df38> in <module>()
      2 #                 1                 #
      3 #####################################
----> 4 import unicodecsv
      5 ## Read in the data from daily_engagement.csv and project_submissions.csv
      6 ## and store the results in the below variables.

ImportError: No module named unicodecsv
```

Answer (score 7):

`Pip` (Package Installer for Python) package manager also comes with Python3, you can try this variant without installing `Conda` (Windows):

```
python -m pip install unicodecsv
```

Answer (score 1):

You should install it (from the command prompt) using:

`conda install unicodecsv`

Comment: I tried that too. When giving conda install unicidecsv, I don't get the list with that package before asking for confirmation. So it's already installed. But when run through Jupiter it fails with "no module with that name"

Comment: Can you paste the specific error message (the entire traceback) that you get?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for the same file at Udacity.

Try changing the Kernel from Python2 to Python3 in the `Kernel -> Change Kernel` menu.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Install unicodecsv using:

```
sudo pip install unicodecsv
```

Restart/run your notebook again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Switching to Python 3 requires you to learn the new syntax and the rest of the nanodegree uses Python 2.

Make sure you are running the notebook in the same environment you are installing the the unicodecsv package in. Then:

```
 conda install unicodecsv
```

should work. It did for me.